# How to generate column values based off of a range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range

I want to make `Start_time(s)` and `End_time(s)` into a range of values in the way they appears in the dataframe for example (0.1, 2.5) so that I can use it to extract ranges of values (time, in seconds) in the second dataframe below:

```
   Words    Start_time(in sec)  End_time(in secs)   Time_per_words
0   let         0.1                 2.5                2.6
1   me          2.5                 2.6                5.1
2   tell        2.6                 2.9                5.5
3   you         2.9                 3.0                5.9
4   about       3.0                 3.2                6.2
5    4          10.7                11.0               21.7
```

Instead of manually calculating for each one of the ranges:

```
df = amp[amp['Time'].between(0.1, 2.5)]
df = df.sort_values('Amplitudes', ascending=False)[:5]
df.head()
```

This dataframe is amp.head():

```
        Time    Amplitudes
1220673 5.36    0.000155
1220674 1.36    0.000936
1220675 0.18    0.001319
1220676 2.36    0.001513
1220677 0.45    0.001666
1220678 1.06    0.001476
1220679 0.17    0.000820
1220680 55.36   0.000409
1220681 55.36   0.000227
1220682 0.09    0.000847
1220683 0.46    0.001333
1220684 1.26    0.001595
1220685 0.30    0.001481
1220686 55.36   0.001312
1220687 55.36   0.002050
```

Expected output:

```
    Words    Start_time(in sec)  End_time(in secs)   Total_Time_words  Amplitude
0    let            0.1               2.5                 2.6            0.23
1    me             2.5               2.6                 5.1            0.12
2    tell           2.6               2.9                 5.5            0.09
3    you            2.9               3.0                 5.9            1.20
4    about          3.0               3.2                 6.2            0.67
```

Comment: Can you explian more how is count `0.23` for first `Amplitude` from sample data?

Comment: I want to select only "Start_time(in sec)" and "End_time(in secs)" column so per index so that i can use it to look for time frame across the second dataframe so that i can now slect the top 5 amplitude of each and take the mean. for example index 0 : between 0.1 and 2.5 on this dataframe below and do so for others on from the above dataframe .... The 0.23 is just an example, just showing a new data will be calulated for each of the word

Comment: please check this links thanks, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350781/how-do-i-compare-two-dataframe-using-between-function-on-the-other-dataframe/62350912#62350912

Comment: df = amp[amp['Time'].between(0.1, 2.5)]
df = df.sort_values('Amplitudes', ascending=False)[:5]
df.head()
this is what i want to achieve, but i want to automate that instead of manually calculating for each words, and then populate the result to the first dataframe

Comment: hmmm, so need mean or top5? Or top5 means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) for binning by `start` and `end` intervals, then aggregate `mean`s and add to original:

```
bins = np.insert(df['End_time(in secs)'].values, 0, df['Start_time(in sec)'].iat[0])
print (bins)
[ 0.1  2.5  2.6  2.9  3.   3.2 11. ]

b = pd.cut(amp['Time'], bins=bins, labels=df['End_time(in secs)'])
s = amp.groupby(b)['Amplitudes'].mean().rename(index=float)
df = df.join(s, on='End_time(in secs)')
print (df)
   Words  Start_time(in sec) End_time(in secs)  Time_per_words  Amplitudes
0    let                 0.1               2.5             2.6    0.001349
1     me                 2.5               2.6             5.1         NaN
2   tell                 2.6               2.9             5.5         NaN
3    you                 2.9                 3             5.9         NaN
4  about                 3.0               3.2             6.2         NaN
5      4                10.7                11            21.7    0.000155
```

If there are not conssecutive groups like first 5 rows:

```
d = {e:amp.loc[amp['Time'].between(s, e), 'Amplitudes'].mean() 
     for s, e in df[['Start_time(in sec)','End_time(in secs)']].to_numpy()}

df['Amplitudes'] = df['End_time(in secs)'].map(d)
print (df)
   Words  Start_time(in sec)  End_time(in secs)  Time_per_words  Amplitudes
0    let                 0.1                2.5             2.6    0.001349
1     me                 2.5                2.6             5.1         NaN
2   tell                 2.6                2.9             5.5         NaN
3    you                 2.9                3.0             5.9         NaN
4  about                 3.0                3.2             6.2         NaN
5      4                10.7               11.0            21.7         NaN
```

Comment: let me try this, thanks for your time,
Is there a way i can automate, that bins, because i have upto 55sec of time, and dealing with different audio length

Comment: It returns NaN all through

Comment: @nath - Can you check second solution?

Comment: @nath - Also first first solution you can try `s = amp.groupby(b)['Amplitudes'].mean().rename(index=float)`

Comment: Nice answer @jezrael

Comment: 2.5: nan, 2.6: nan, 2.9: nan, 3.0: nan, 3.2: nan, 3.4: nan, 4.0: nan, 4.2: nan, 4.7: nan, 4.9: nan, 5.0: nan, 5.2: nan, 6.4: nan, 6.7: nan, 7.0: nan, 7.3: nan, 7.5: nan, 7.7: nan, 7.8: nan, 7.9: nan, 9.2: nan, 9.4: nan, 9.6: nan, 9.9: nan, 10.3: nan, 10.7: nan, 11.0: nan, 11.7: nan, 12.4: nan, 12.9: nan, 13.7: nan, 13.8: nan, 13.9: nan, 14.1: nan, 14.6: nan, 15.1: nan, 15.3: nan, 15.6: nan, 16.7: nan, 16.8: nan, 16.9: nan, 17.2: nan, 18.0: ...25.6:nan... when i print d, that is what i got

Comment: @nath - SO I guess it is data related problem, are real data confidental?

Comment: no, it is not, it is data, i generated from an audio file, i can share the two dataframe with you

Comment: @nath - ok, super, try share data by gdocs, dropbox...

Comment: i will share with my google drive to ur gmail, or let me try dropbox, either of the two

Comment: please what is your name of dropbox,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215993/discussion-between-nath-and-jezrael).